# Subgrouping in R

Tags: r

I have a vector as such:

```
a<-c(0.8,1,1.2,3,4,5,6)
```

where each value is represented in terms of year and i would like to classify them into three buckets("One year or less","Over one year to five years" and "Over five years")

My code looks like this:

```
AAA_factor <- cut(x = a, breaks = c(0, 1, 5),labels = c("One year or less","Over one year to five years", "Over five years"))
```

When I run this code, it returns me this error:

```
Error in cut.default(x = a, breaks = c(0, 1, 5), labels = c("One year or less",  : 
  lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ
```

How to fix this?

I also want to add subgrouping as part of another column of a.

Tried this:

```
a_group <-data.frame(a,cut(x = a, breaks = c(0, 1, 5),labels = c("One year or less","Over one year to five years", "Over five years"))) 
names(a_group)[2]<-"Time bucket"
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three endpoints will only give 2 regions. Instead, add an upper bound of inifinity

```
AAA_factor <- cut(x = a, breaks = c(0, 1, 5, Inf),
    labels = c("One year or less","Over one year to five years", 
    "Over five years"))
AAA_factor
[1] One year or less            One year or less           
[3] Over one year to five years Over one year to five years
[5] Over one year to five years Over one year to five years
[7] Over five years
```